# Ajax Postdata with cURL

Tags: jquery, ajax, curl

How to manipulate a function of web app. my parameters using cURL??
How can I postdata  in post-fields of Ajax using cURL?

```
{
function voteentry() 
{
    $(".loader").fadeIn()
    $.ajax({
        type     : 'POST',
        url      : "ajax_vote.php",
        data     : "userid="+userid+"&entryid="+entryid,
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.indexOf('1') > 0) {
                $('.votebtn').addClass("transparent");
                getEntries();
                $('#profile-vote').html(parseInt($('#profile-vote').html())+1);

                //votePost(entryid,entryname);
            };
            $(".loader").fadeOut();
            //showCongrats();
        }
    });
```

I know userid and entryid as well but how to post them in database using cURL??

Comment: why exactly do you want to use cURL? as of now, you should receive a normal POST request at your script ajax_vote.php, which you can use as if it was a normal HTTP POST request... If you don't have some 'weird' construction on your webserver, no need to use cURL at all...

Comment: It's not a simply http request that why asking for curl ??

Comment: please explain your situation more extensive: why do you need curl, what is wrong with a normal http request. And foremost: what have you tried, what does ajax_vote.php look like, etc.

Comment: Actually this function is in mine .js page and ajax_vote.php is a count database page as many userids I put count increase so I want to put directly in DB it's not a headers

Comment: yes I identified the snippet as being javascript/jquery... ok I'll try to help you a bit. I guess you want some data (`userid` and `entryid`) to be inserted in a database, right? As you direct your POST request to ajax_vote.php, normally you would something like: `INSERT INTO table SET entyid=$_POST['entryid']`. So please explain: why does that not suit your situation, where does cURL comes in, and, what have you tried?

Comment: Are you trying to simulate this ajax request using cURL?

Comment: How can I simulate it??

Comment: @giorgio I tried this but data not sent and no error as well.cURL have session function which may help in putting data.

Comment: I'm very sorry, but I have to vote to close this question. You do way too little to help us at least get clear what your problem is. You can always try to ask again, no problem at all, but please read [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first.